# Can't checkout a branch, git stuck on .vs/config/applicationhost.config

Tags: git

I am using Git through PowerShell in Visual Studio 2017. When I do a `git status` I see this:

```
PS C:\Dev\JFG\jfg-website> git status
On branch Newsletter-Signup-Subscription-UX
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/Newsletter-Signup-Subscription-UX'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .vs/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

If I try to checkout another branch:

```
PS C:\Dev\JFG\jfg-website> git checkout master
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        .vs/config/applicationhost.config
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

If I try to remove that file from source control:

```
PS C:\Dev\JFG\jfg-website> git rm .vs/config/applicationhost.config --cached
fatal: pathspec '.vs/config/applicationhost.config' did not match any files
```

I've also tried `git rm .vs --cached`. If I do a `git clean -n`, nothing happens, the `.vs/` folder still appears as untracked. Same for `git clean -f`.

I am only having this problem on one of my branches. Trying to figure out why it's happening. Very strange that Git is stopping me from checking out another branch, then says the file actually can't be found. FWIW, the file *does* exist on disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a `git clean -d .vs -f` to remove the folder itself, which has allowed me to check out another branch. The `.vs/` folder still shows up as untracked though.